# update and insert into Azure data warehouse using Azure data factory pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to run an adf copy pipeline with and update and insert statements that is supposed to replace merge statement. basically a statement like:

```
UPDATE TARGET 
SET ProductName = SOURCE.ProductName, 
TARGET.Rate = SOURCE.Rate 
FROM  Products AS TARGET
INNER JOIN UpdatedProducts AS SOURCE 
ON TARGET.ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID
WHERE TARGET.ProductName <> SOURCE.ProductName 
OR TARGET.Rate <> SOURCE.Rate

INSERT Products (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) 
SELECT SOURCE.ProductID, SOURCE.ProductName, SOURCE.Rate
FROM UpdatedProducts AS SOURCE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID
)
```

If the target is an azure sql db I would use this way: https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/04/20/upsert-to-azure-sql-db-with-azure-data-factory
but if the target is an adw a stored procedure option doesn't exist! any suggestion? do I have to have a staging table first then I run the update and insert statements from stg_table to target_table? or maybe there is any possibility to do it directly from adf?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a stored procedure, my suggestion would be to create a second copy data transform. Run the pre-script on the second transform and drop the table since its a temp table that you created on the first.

```
BEGIN

MERGE Target AS target_sqldb
USING TempTable AS source_tblstg
ON (target_sqldb.Id= source_tblstg.Id)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    [Name] = source_tblstg.Name,
    [State] = source_tblstg.State

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT([Name], [State])
    VALUES (source_tblstg.Name, source_tblstg.State);

DROP TABLE TempTable;

END
```